# Angular $http allow cross origin

Tags: angularjs, http

```
        var sourceURL = http://www.example.basic.ics;
        var IcsData = null;
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'text/calendar',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://mysiteexample.com',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT',
            }
        };

        function getIcsData(sourceURL, config) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(sourceURL, config)
            .then(function(success){
                console.log('success:', success);
                deferred.resolve(success)
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('error', error);
                deferred.reject(error);
            })
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        getIcsData(sourceURL);
```

I'm trying to make a http request to receive ics data so that I can parse it to JSON.  The issue is that when I try to make the http request I get an error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.basic.ics. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mysiteexample.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm struggling here.